# Backbone navigation issue

Tags: backbone.js, reactjs, backbone-events, backbone-routing

I'm using backbone.js with react.js. I am using backbone routers to navigate.

Before navigating from one page to another page I'm creating a backbone event and passing some data through it. I'm listening to the same event in the next page. Till this point everything is fine. After that I'm moving from that page to other by using backbone routers only. But then I'm trying to go back with browser back button. Navigation working properly but data is not being displayed.

Comment: Please post some codes.

Comment: is this a backbone problem or react problem?

Comment: I don't think it is problem with react or backbone. Both are working as they should. But I'm having problem with the combining both of them. @BlairAnderson

Comment: I have them working together on many projects. its probably your backbone router.